# Glassfish server MultiException

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I have a problem with starting a GlassFish server. I set it properly, because it worked, but next day I was trying to run it again, and I have a MultiException. Can someone tell me what's going on? I attach logs below:

```
MultiException stack 1 of 7
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/enterprise/util/LocalStringManagerImpl
MultiException stack 2 of 7
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on org.glassfish.security.services.impl.AuthenticationServiceImpl
MultiException stack 3 of 7
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of org.glassfish.security.services.impl.NucleusInternalSystemAdministrator errors were found
MultiException stack 4 of 7
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on org.glassfish.security.services.impl.NucleusInternalSystemAdministrator
MultiException stack 5 of 7
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.ConnectorResourceManagerLifecycleListener errors were found
MultiException stack 6 of 7
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.ConnectorResourceManagerLifecycleListener
MultiException stack 7 of 7
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.listener.ResourceManager
```